# How to get data from 2D array and put into 1D array

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a 2D array and I want to create a 1D by MATLAB, satisfying the requirement that each element of the 1D output was created by the value of a given index into the 2D array. Example 2D array is

```
A=[2 4 6; 1 9 7.3 4 5]
```

And indexes for the 1D array

```
X=[1;2;3]
Y=[1;2;3]
```

I want to store the 1D array with elements determined by

```
 B=A(x,y) % x,y are index in X and Y matrix
```

Example of building the 1D array:

```
X=[1;2;3]
Y=[1;2;3]

 B=[A(1,1);A(2,2);A(3,3)]=[2; 9; 5]
```

This is my code

```
B=zeros(1,length(A));
B=A(...)  %I don't know it
```

How can I implement it?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A=[2 4 6; 1 9 7; 3 4 5]
X=[1;2;3]; Y=[1;2;3];
B = A(sub2ind(size(A),X,Y))

B =

     2
     9
     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cellfun` to do it. You convert A into cell by column, and execute `f` for each element of the cell.

```
 A=[2 4 6; 1 2 7];

 % some example f funcion that just adds the col_index_A and row_index_A
 f = @(col_index_A, row_index_A) col_index_A + row_index_A; 

 % execute f with parameters that come from each column of A
 B = cellfun(@(c) f(c(1), c(2)), num2cell(A, 1));

 B =

     3     6    13
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but i think you want to apply functions on a 2-by-n matrix

Try

```
for pos=1:size(a,2)
  b(pos) = f(a(:,pos));
end
```